# Edit distance for huge strings with bounds

Tags: algorithms, edit-distance

My question is simple but I don't know if the answer is.

> If you have two strings of length 10 million each, is there an algorithm that would allow you in
>   practice to compute their [edit distance (Levenshtein)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) if you are told
>   it is at most 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the usual [dynamic programming algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm). Instead of computing the edit distance between *all* prefixes of the input strings, compute only the edit distance between prefixes whose length is at most 100 apart. This reduces the number of entries to compute from $10^{14}$ to roughly $2\cdot 10^9$, which is feasible.

Comment: Does this method need the same amount of space?

Comment: The DP solution only requires storing two rows, and the same should be true here.